# Can not catch the custom intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a activity and one button make shortcut + custom intent with my action inside. After I'm click the button, it's work well, a shortcut already on homescreen. Then I click shortcut, main activity **can not catch the intent in my receiver class**. Where am I wrong?

**Main Activity**

I have rigister Reciever in onCreate(), with intent filter.

```
registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), new IntentFilter("nhq.intent.flashlight"));
```

This is my Reciever class inside MainActivity

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
                // onPause() will be called.
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
                // Handle resuming events
            }
        }

    }
```

When I click the button make shortcut I run the function

```
private void makeShortcut() {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction("nhq.intent.flashlight"); 

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"Flash Light");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent); 

        //finish();
    }
```

I also defined reciever in manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nhq.fashlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <!-- Camera Requirement -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <!-- Camera Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- Features -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="nhq.fashlight.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="nhq.fashlight.MainActivity$MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nhq.intent.flashlight" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-read the question (sorry) and it seems you have a typo in your package names:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nhq.fashlight"

shortcutIntent.setAction("nhq.intent.flashlight");
```

That maybe why the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explan for me why when I have a type "nhq.flashlight", the shortcut doesn't work??

Comment: @QuocNguyen so is your package nhq.flashlight now not fashlight and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

i think that need addAction for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, ON, PRESENT.

like this

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
```

also add ACTION_SCREEN_ON,ACTION_USER_PRESENT filter.addAction too.
then receive intent action

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
                // onPause() will be called.
            }
```